# buildroot compiling driver

Tags: compiling, drivers, buildroot

I'm using Buildroot for compiling embedded linux. It works well because I have target Makefile configurations, but now I need driver for my usb devices. I manage to compile Qt appilactions(c++) on my host linux to target linux by using buildroots `/output/host/usr/bin/arm-none-linux-gnueabi-c++` . Works well.

Now I'm trying to compile c-files for [this driver](http://www.ftdichip.com/Drivers/VCP.htm).

I'm calling it like:

```
/output/host/usr/bin/arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc -Wall -D__KERNEL__ -DMODULE -I/home/buildroot-2012.08/output/build/linux-2.6.35.3/include -DMODVERSIONS -include /home/buildroot-2012.08/output/build/linux-2.6.35.3/include/config/modversions.h -I /home/buildroot-2012.08/output/build/linux-2.6.35.3/drivers/usb/serial/ -O   -c -o ftdi_sio.o ftdi_sio.c
```

I'm getting error:

> output/build/linux-2.6.35.3/include/linux/linkage.h:5: fatal error: asm/linkage.h: No such file or directory

1. How I should configurate the driver compiling?
2. Is there some other way to do it for target linux. Mayby I'm not doing it the right way.

Comment: Buildroot is an integrated build environment, so you better take a look how to create a recipe for kernel module to integrate it to kernel build process. There is no point in using Buildroot if you still compile applications, kernel modules manually.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`asm/` is a symbolic link to your target architecture, if it doesn't exist probably you're missing some target in your kernel build directory, `configure` (if not, maybe just `module_headers` can make it)

It is not clear from your question if you're using the command line, a custom Makefile, or a Buildroot package (which version of Buildroot are you using).

Your command line is building a C object `.o` not a kernel module (`.o` was the extension for kernel modules till the version 2.4, from 2.6 it is `.ko`)

If you are not sure about the flags increase the verbosity for the build of the kernel modules, build and log, then use the same.

The kernel have its way to [build modules](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/lkmpg/2.6/html/x181.html) and the Buildroot have its way for packages, the best is probably to create a new package to build your module (take a look if there's already some other package that build a module).

[This example](http://buildroot-busybox.2317881.n4.nabble.com/Adding-package-that-builds-Kernel-Module-ko-to-Buildroot-environment-td30442.html) is a bit old but maybe help.

**edit**

The `ftdi_sio.ko` module is generated into the directory `/lib/modules/$(uname -r)/kernel/drivers/usb/serial/`

But it could be configured as `builtin` also, so that no `.ko` is generated, check the symbol [USB_SERIAL_FTDI_SIO](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/usb/serial/Makefile?v=2.6.35) in your [configuration](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/usb/serial/Kconfig?v=2.6.35#L153) (should be `y` for builtin `m` for module).

If it is builtin or inserted there should be a `/proc` interface at runtime on the target called [ftdi_sio](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/usb/serial/ftdi_sio.c?v=2.6.35#L857), find it.

Comment: It looks like that driver should be FTDI USB UART built in to kernel. How I can check that on buildroot?

Comment: Looks like its on output also, /buildroot-2012.08/output/build/linux-2.6.35.3/drivers/usb/serial/ftdi_sio.c But how it's not on the target distor?

Comment: I mange to install it and added it by # modprobe ftdi_sio vendor=0x0403 product=0x6001, but I can't get any infromation from ttyUSB0

Comment: That's another question :) [see here](http://www.elinux.org/Hammer_How_to_USB_FTDI) and [here](http://www.sealevel.com/support/article/AA-00524) hope it help. [sertest.c](http://websvn.hylands.org/filedetails.php?repname=Projects&path=%2Fhost%2Fsertest%2Fsertest.c&rev=80&peg=80).